# Jest snapshot testing React component with randomly generated id (uuid)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, uuid

I am trying to create jest snapshot test for a React component that generates unique id using uuid. I am trying to mock the uuid functionality. But mocking does not seem to be working.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import v1 from 'uuid/v1';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // Other codes ...

  render() {
    const id = v1();
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={id}>
          <input type="checkbox"/>  
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('<MyComponent/>', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    jest.mock('uuid/v1', () => jest.fn(() => 1));
    const tree = renderer.create(<Checkbox />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Does it work if you put `jest.mock('uuid/v1', () => jest.fn(() => 1));` before the `describe` block? Cause I could imaging that `MyComponent` uses the original one when the mocking happens inside the `describe` block

Comment: @AndreasKöberle thank you very much. Yes `MyComponent` was using the original one instead of the mock function. And it works when I move it before the `describe` block. But I wonder why is it the case. In my existing code, I am mocking before i create the snapshot in the test. Also, if I move mocking before describe, what would I do if I needed to mock it with different return values for different tests? Thanks again.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, mocking inside `beforeEach` or `beforeAll` before or inside the `describe` block do not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you mock the module after you import the module that you want to test. So the imported module has the original version of `uuid/v1` imported. Then you mock `uuid/v1` but this will have no effect on `MyComponent` as this already have the reference to the original version.

When using `jest.mock` in the most outer block of your test, it will be hoisted to the top of the module, so jest will mock `uuid/v1` before it can be imported  into `MyComponent` that's why it works in this case